The effects of optical-flow sensor on takeoff and landing of drones
Does installing optical flow and rangefinder sensors improve the smoothness of takeoffs and landings on drones? Specifically, can these sensors enhance stability during these phases even if advanced flight modes like Position Hold and Altitude Hold are not enabled?
